# How to assign roles to existing users using ngx permission in angular 2 application

Tags: permissions, angular-ngmodel

i am implementing role based access to my application. I have already created the permissions and also assigned that permi8ssions to the roles. i am referring [this](https://github.com/JavadRasouli/ng2-permission/blob/master/doc/managing-permissions.md) link for my role based architecture.

But now i am not getting any idea about how to assign users to that roles, so that application will work fine according to role based architecture.

How to assign roles to user?